# Is using begin() and end() of an empty std::vector well defined?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Presume that I am copying a `std::vector` into a `std::vector` with `std::vector::insert` (as below).

The question is: when the vector that I am copying from is empty, are `begin()` and `end()` well defined in all circumstances for purposes of the `std::vector::insert` call?

The reason I ask is this sentence:

> If `allocator_traits::construct` is not supported with the appropriate arguments for the element constructions, **or if an invalid position or range is specified, it causes undefined behavior.**

https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

void printbytes(char* bytes, size_t len) {
    if(len == 0) return;
    for(size_t i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", *(bytes+i) & 0xff);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> target = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
    std::vector<char> source = {'w','o','r','l','d'};

    //defined
    target.insert(target.end(), source.begin(), source.end());
    printbytes(target.data(), target.size());

    //is this defined?
    source.clear();
    target.insert(target.end(), source.begin(), source.end());
    printbytes(target.data(), target.size());

    //how about this?
    std::vector<char> boo;
    boo.insert(boo.end(), source.begin(), source.end());
    printbytes(boo.data(), boo.size());
}
```

Comment: yes, `begin()` and `end()` are well-defined for empty vectors (and will test equal in that case). The end of a vector (empty or not) is a valid insert position

Comment: Yes.  `begin()` and `end()` are well defined for an empty vector.   They will compare equal (so, for example, range-based loops won't execute the body at all) and you should avoid dereferencing either of them (as doing so will access a non-existent element).  Inserting is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `begin()` and `end()` always work. We know this because `std::vector` satisfies the *Container* requirement, and `begin()` is defined as follows:

> ```cpp
> b.begin()
> ```
>
> *Result*: `iterator`; `const_iterator` for constant `b`.
> *Returns*: An iterator referring to the first element in the container.
> *Complexity*: Constant.

- [[container.reqmts]](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.reqmts#lib:begin,containers)

This function has no preconditions, so it must always work, even for empty, and even for moved-from vectors.

Furthermore, all calls to `insert` you're making are well-defined because the requirements for a *SequenceContainer* in [[sequence.reqmts]](https://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts) (which `std::vector` satisfies) require only the following for `insert(p, i, j)`, where `p`, `i`, `j` are iterators:

> ```cpp
> a.insert(p, i, j)
> ```
>
> *Result*: `iterator`.
> *Preconditions*: [Type constraints.] Neither `i` nor `j` are iterators into `a`.
> [...]

Namely, it's not required by `insert` that `[i, j)` is a non-empty range.

---

On a side note, **cplusplus.com** is massively out-of-date in a lot of cases. **[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/)** is more actively maintained, though it's sometimes wrong and incomplete. When in doubt, refer directly to the C++ standard.

Comment: There have been issues in the past with begin/end returning a null pointer in this case, and the caller passing that to memcpy, which does not support null pointer arguments. Something to be aware of.

Comment: @MarcGlisse that's a good point. I wonder though, since `std::vector::begin()` isn't required to be a pointer, wouldn't you normally use `data()` for `memcpy`?

Comment: If you are passing it directly to memcpy, yes, data() is more relevant indeed. But if you are passing it to std::copy or some other standard function that may be specialized to call memcpy for some types of iterators... (the issue was thus probably a bug in those standard library implementations and has thus likely been fixed a while ago) so maybe my comment wasn't that relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. Empty range (i.e., one where `first == last`) is a valid range. An example of invalid range would be one where `first` and `last` iterators are not from the same container, one or both iterators are invalidated or if they came from the same container as you try to insert into.

Personally, I wouldn't use cplusplus.com, it's very outdated. And the way they explain things doesn't seem clear either (as seen by your question). Use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) instead.

Comment: cplusplus.com is clearly laid out and has always about perfect balance between informative and succinct. It is "to the point".
cppreference.com on the other hand appears bloated, has way too much information and oftentimes is a difficult read. 
Now I know this latter site is up to date while the former site is not, but for everything up to C++14 I find cplusplus.com a preferable reference.

Comment: cplusplus.com thinks C++11 is the latest and greatest, and is incomplete for C++11, C++14, and it doesn't even know anything else exists. It is exactly because it is out of date that it is a garbage reference. You literally can't know if you're missing anything. Like a modal text editor, cppreference takes time to get accustomed with, but once you do, it's fantastic.

Comment: @Giogre I stand by my opinion. Given that C++14 is a decade old now, I do find it obsolete. I couldn't use it to get information for work for example. And I find several parts of cplusplus formatting just bad. Like, when they decide to put several constructors on one line and dump a lot of spaces in for whatever reason: https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/. Cprreference may be giving out too much information at times, but at least it's complete and correct information. Not the reference's fault that C++ is a difficult language.

Comment: The legacy version of cplusplus.com is correctly formatted https://legacy.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ Sadly, what update they introduced, the new graphic layout a couple of years ago, is more a degradation than an enhancement. I don't know why the author stop updating the site 10 years ago. Same reason Scott Meyers "retired" from C++?